# Magento 2 : How to represent multiple option attribute while importing product with csv

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am working on magento 2.1.3

I was trying to import product with multiple option attribute.

Eg :  Attribute name : **tv_features**

**values are :  TV Monitor,Smart TV,UHD TV,3D TV**

How can i represent multiple option attribute in additional_attributes column..??

Eg : `has_options=0,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0,brand_name=LG,tv_screen_type=LED,tv_screen_size=65",tv_features=Smart TV,UHD TV,3D TV, tv_hdmi_ports=3, tv_usb_ports=3`

Comment: Are you want to import multiple select value attribute?

Comment: Yes correct.. I want to import multiple value attribute

Comment: I am still facing this issue on a M2 2.4.2 installation. found a valid solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use **`PIPE(|) separator`** for multiple select attribute value.

ex.

```
tv_features=Smart TV|UHD TV|3D TV
```

Using Pipe separator you can import your multiple select attribute value in magento 2.

Comment: but it is not working, I am also using pipeline separator

Comment: Pipe did not work for me - the system did not seperate the values by the pipe, instead it added new attributes to the system like: "Smart TV|UHD TV|3D TV". Comma seperated also did not work as I get the infamous "column contains an incorrect value". I think it is fair to say at this point I dislike Magento.

Comment: Does not work for me